# Excel Cell reference that will go to the left

Tags: vba, excel, reference, cell

I am using an excel spreadsheet formula to add two cells together and I want to have it reference one row from left to right like it normally does, but I need it to reference the same row in another page in reverse, and then be able to drag the formula through the entire worksheet. I cannot seem to find anything like this when I look online. TLDR I need to know how to tell excel reference the cell to the left if I drag it to the right.

so I need to add A0 in page one and A9 in page two then when I copy the formula to the left I need it to grab A1 and A8, is there a way to get this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.  For your page 2 reference, I would suggest looking at the OFFSET function

Comment: What is A0? Is it a cell address?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear; for example, you talk about a formula but have an Excel-VBA tag.  However, I think I understand the effect you seek.

I have filled A1:I1 of the current sheet and A1:I1 of worksheet “Sheet3” with numbers.

I have typed the following formula into another cell within the current worksheet:

```
=A1+INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1,,10-COLUMN(A1))
```

The target area for the INDEX function is `Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1`.  This is a one row range so I do not need a row number.  The column number is `10-COLUMN(A1)` which is 9 so this formula is equivalent to:

```
=A1+Sheet3!I9
```

If I copy the formula one cell to the right I get:

```
=B1+INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1,,10-COLUMN(B1))
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
=B1+Sheet3!H9
```

You can continue copying the formula to the right until you get:

```
=I1+INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1,,10-COLUMN(I1))
```

Attempting to copy further gives an error because `10-COLUMN(J1)` is zero and there is no column 0.

There are other methods of achieving this effect.  The key feature of any such method is the expression `N-X` where N is a constant and X gets bigger as the formula is copied further to the right.

Comment: How would you get it to be able to copy down rows as well, I tried to have it call the same row as the current cell and I keep getting a ref error

=B1+INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1, ROW(B1),10-COLUMN(B1))

Comment: @Wraith40k.  `Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1` identifies a single row. `ROW(B1)` has a value of 1 which is OK. But `ROW(B2)` has a value of 2 and there is no row 2 within `Sheet3!$A$1:$I$1`.  With `Sheet3!$A$1:$I$5` you can pull down 5 rows before getting an error.